# The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context on an Android project

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm having issues building my android app - it throws this error on all pages. Building iOS app goes fine. I tried to build this project on windows and got the same error. Unfortunately I don't remember what caused it.

What can cause this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that I am aware of that can cause this error is the Android project not being able to find the InitializeComponent method. VS 2015 has a lot of intellisense issues around this but it doesn't stop you from building.

Also it might be working on iOS because your only running an old version of the code for iOS.

I would try the following

1. Make sure you have Xamarin.Forms installed
2. If you do reinstall all your NuGet packages. You can type this in the Package Manager Console

update-package -project enter_project_name -reinstall

3. Make sure you don't have any errors in your references.

Comment: Yep, after updating packages I was able to build Android project. Thank you very much. But how could it happened?

Comment: Xamarin and VS both can corrupt or have incomplete setups due to reasons I haven't had the time to really investigate. However a reinstall or reset of sorts, normally resolves any of these types of issues and when you are on a tight deadline, its the quickest way to get back up and running.